How to get dataplex Lake, Zone, Asset iam permission using python?
Is there any pythonic way to get the lis of roles and principals assigned to GCP dataplex Lakes, Zones, Assets.
I found below gcloud command to get the roles, but I need relevant python method.
gcloud dataplex lakes get-iam-policy dp-lake-test --location=us

I see there is a REST API ... https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.lakes/getIamPolicy ... but odly I couldn't seet a get_iam_policy method where I expected it ... https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataplex/latest/google.cloud.dataplex_v1.services.dataplex_service.DataplexServiceClient
